# Tax not showing in shopping cart in Magento 2

Tags: tax, shopping-cart, taxes

We have setup all our tax classes and tax settings in Magento 2 and everything is working perfect, only in the shopping cart the tax is not calculated in the grand total. In the rest of the checkout proces and in orders it does show up. We have setup "display prices" to yes and I included down here a printscreen with the settings:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why the tax is not showing up in the cart?

Comment: Is there a solution for this yet? I have the same problem. I already have my Shipping Origin (`Stores > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Settings > Origin`) set. Have you tried this Coen?

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem as well. Somehow my products were all set to **Tax Class: none**. I had configured taxes correctly, but in the shopping cart it was still showing zero taxes.

The issue was solved by accessing the product details:
*Catalog > Products > View Product*

Change tax class to "Taxable Goods" or whatever your tax class name is.

[image]

Comment: There is no such field called "Tax Class"

Comment: I am facing similar issue, I have the `taxable goods` selected also my settings are correct from: `Shopping Cart Display Settings`  . Any idea what else should I try ?

Answer (score 3):

Change the settings
**Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Settings -> Origin**

Expand this tab and change the country to your country.

Comment: Worked for me , thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue then I noticed that I have not selected countries under Store->Configuration->Sales->Tax->Integration Setting->Allowed Countries

[image]