# Tax value is not displayed in the cart issue on Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, tax-rule

I found this similar [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158534/tax-not-showing-in-shopping-cart-in-magento-2), but I might have a different problem.

In the below images, you can see my settings:
[image]
[image]
[image]

**The interesting part is that my tax looks to have the value of **zero**. See:**

[image]

**After that ajax is loaded, the tax dissappears!**  . My tax rule is set to 21% from `Stores -> Tax rules`
I don't know what other settings should I check ? Would you please suggest me something to check ?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From **Tax Rule Information**: I didn't have the right tax set for the country :( . See img:
[image]

I leave this info here, maybe it will help someone!